# How to find out count month vise in particular day range sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Like

| date | count users |
| --- | --- |
| 2 jan - 7 feb |  |
| 2 feb - 7 march |  |

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output. It would be also nice if you explain these strange date-intervals

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by month with the month including anything from the 3rd of one month until the 2nd of the following month you can use:

```
GROUP BY date_part('month', event_date - interval '2 day');
```

If your month runs from the 2nd of one month to the 7th of the following all events between the 2nd and the 7th will be counted twice.